# Using mockito to stub a void method

Tags: android, mockito

```
mockito-core:2.7.10
```

I am testing the following method using mockito

```
@Override
public void detachView() {
    mMovieListViewContract = null;
    mMovieModelContract.releaseResources();
}
```

I am stubbing the releaseResources method which has a void return. And testing to ensure the stubbed version gets called only once.

```
@Override
public void releaseResources() {
    if(mSubscription != null && !mSubscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

I have written the following test:

```
@Test
public void shouldReleaseModelResourcesWhenDetached() {
   doNothing().when(mockMovieListModelContract).releaseResources();

   movieListPresenterContract.detachView();

   verify(mockMovieListModelContract, times(1)).releaseResources();
}
```

I want to verify that the stubbed version of `mockMovieListModelContract.releaseResources()` gets called just once.
The following failed the test:

```
verify(mockMovieListModelContract, times(1)).releaseResources();
```

The test failed with:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
movieListModelContract.releaseResources();
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

So I changed to using `verifyZeroInteractions(mockMovieListModelContract);` which passed the test. However, the test to verify that the stubbed version gets called just once.

Comment: Can you show the full test method? Mock and Before and Spy annotation usages are the most interest to me

Comment: The code shown here looks good. Could it be a initialization problem ? i.e. `mockMovieListModelContract` is not injected in the `movieListPresenterContract` instance.

Comment: Thanks guys, you was correct I wasn't injecting the MovieListModelContract in the constructor of the MovieListPresenterImp. I was using Dagger2 dependency injection and forgot to add this.

Comment: Just for the record: in case my answer helped here; consider accepting at some point. Or let me know what is missing to get it accept-worthy ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of straight forward: the mocking framework tells you that this method wasn't invoked on that mock object.

There are only **two** explanations for that:

- You are **not** really running the production code you are showing in your question (you are testing something else)
- Something is wrong with your setup; and you are **not** "inserting" the mocked object when doing the test setup